# Spark - How can get the Logical / Physical Query execution using - Thirft - Hive Interactor

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark - How can get the Logical / Physical Query execution using the following

1. Via Thrift
2. Via SparkInteractor

Comment: Hi San, Did it answer what you are looking for.? or do you need any other information

Answer (score 5):

You can use explain statement with query as below in beeline via thrift.

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED select * from sr23 join sr12 [<join condidtion>]
```

What do you mean be spark interceptor.? is it spark-sql shell.? if it is, then you can use above query.

If you meant spark-shell, then you need to call explain() function on dataframes.

eg:

```
val df1 = sqlContext.sql(" < your sql query > ");

df1.explain;
```

this will give both physical and logical plans. You can also see them from spark web UI in SQL tab.

Comment: .explain() works as it prints the physical plan on the console (nice and neat) but it doesn't show anything on the sql tab. Is that normal?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Spark 1, You can get the explain on a query this way:

```
sqlContext.sql("your SQL query").explain(true)
```

If you are using Spark 2, it's the same:

```
spark.sql("your SQL query").explain(true)
```

The same logic is available on a dataframe:

```
yourDF.explain(true) or yourDF.someOperation.explain(true)
```

Where someOperation could be maybe a select on a join or something else.