# Can Spark take advantage of partitioned hive table to reduce IO?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a 14 billion table and I am scanning for 3 months of data , I can see number of task are 9439 . Same table I am scanning for 1 month and number of tasks are exactly same 9439.
My table is partitioned by months , so what i believe spark is not taking advantage of partition table .

Is it correct behavior ! Please help me if i am missing any thing .

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: What's your table storage format (csv, parquet,...) ?

Comment: What is your cluster capacity? How many executors do you have and what is the mem & cores per executor?

Comment: storage format is parquet . Cluster is of 34 nodes , each nodehas 200 TB of. hard disk and ram of 200GB . I have taken 50 executor,executor memory 30 GB , executor core 4 .

Comment: Did you check the Spark execution plan? Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35883620/spark-how-can-get-the-logical-physical-query-execution-using-thirft-hive

Comment: How do you specify the partition key - in a SQL "WHERE" clause, or a Spark API call? with an equality operator, a range operator, something else?

Comment: BTW, which version of Spark are you using???

Comment: spark 1.6, in sql I am giving a where clause !